# Implemeting Single Sign On Extension in for iOS 13 app

Tags: ios, swift, single-sign-on, ios13

I want to implement **Single Sign On Extension** for an iOS 13 app. I've already gone through various blogs, but there seems to be no standard solution available for implementing single sign-on extensions.

I'm trying to build up my own SSO solution, but I've not yet been able to implement it successfully. Here is the code that I have written so far:

```
import UIKit
import AuthenticationServices

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    
    @IBAction func loginButtonPushed(_ sender: Any) {
        let issuer = URL(fileURLWithPath: "https://url_here")
        let ssoProvider = ASAuthorizationSingleSignOnProvider(identityProvider: issuer)
        let request = ssoProvider.createRequest()
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
        request.authorizationOptions = [
            URLQueryItem(name: "client_id", value: "client_id"),
            URLQueryItem(name: "response_type", value: "code")
        ]
        let authzController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        authzController.delegate = self
        authzController.presentationContextProvider = self
        authzController.performRequests()
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
    }
    
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
        // Handle error.
    }
}

extension ViewController: ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding {
    func presentationAnchor(for controller: ASAuthorizationController) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
        return self.view.window!
    }
}
```

More generally, I'd like to ask:

1. What are the prerequisites to an SSO solution that we need to consider before implementation.

   - Questions Like:

     - What type of server required,
     - Which auth services need to implement and why,
     - Do we need to consider Apple configurator2 for implementing this?
2. Is there anything that need to be done at server-side? If yes, please explain it. I need to understand both the back-end and development perspectives.
3. There are two different types of extensions provided by iOS 13 for SSO implementations: redirect and credential.

[image]

So, how should we decide which extension to implement and why? What circumstances do we need to consider in making the decision?